# In lightningChart, how can I lock the Y axis of 2 or more axes in order to keep the zero always in sync?

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, lightningchart

I need to display voltage and current on the same 2D graph (LightningChart.ViewXY). To keep values in a visible proportion, I uses 2 different axes. But my customers and I would like to ensure the zero will always be aligned together between the 2 different axes. Is that possible and if yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Eric for asking this. 
The chart and axes have events to aid you with custom handling of cases like this. 
As far as remember there is no property to several YAxes at same horizontal position, e.g. Zoomed, Panned event handle and modify Axis’ range accordingly. Below is example how to fix reference value of two axes (same segment) to the middle of graph area.

```
    private void ViewXY_Zoomed(object sender, Arction.Wpf.Charting.Views.ViewXY.ZoomedXYEventArgs e)
    {
        AxisY axis0 = _chart.ViewXY.YAxes[0];
        AxisY axis1 = _chart.ViewXY.YAxes[1];

        // get segment top & bottom coordinates [PX]
        GraphSegmentInfo gsi = _chart.ViewXY.GetGraphSegmentInfo();
        float fTop = gsi.SegmentTops[0];
        float fBottom = gsi.SegmentBottoms[0];

        int iScreenCoordForRefValue = (int)(fTop + fBottom) / 2;
        float fAxis0RefValue = 50, fAxis1RefValue = 0;

        double dAxis0ValueAtCoord, dAxis1ValueAtCoord;
        axis0.CoordToValue(iScreenCoordForRefValue, out dAxis0ValueAtCoord, false);
        axis1.CoordToValue(iScreenCoordForRefValue, out dAxis1ValueAtCoord, false);

        // pan Axis' RefValue position at RefScreenCoord
        double dNewMinAxis0 = axis0.Minimum - (dAxis0ValueAtCoord - fAxis0RefValue);
        double dNewMaxAxis0 = axis0.Maximum - (dAxis0ValueAtCoord - fAxis0RefValue);
        double dNewMinAxis1 = axis1.Minimum - (dAxis1ValueAtCoord - fAxis1RefValue);
        double dNewMaxAxis1 = axis1.Maximum - (dAxis1ValueAtCoord - fAxis1RefValue);

        _chart.BeginUpdate();

        axis0.SetRange(dNewMinAxis0, dNewMaxAxis0);
        axis1.SetRange(dNewMinAxis1, dNewMaxAxis1);

        _chart.EndUpdate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function alignChartHorizontally(chart) {
    chart.getDefaultAxisY().setThickness({
        min: 60
    })
}

if(yourFirstChart.show) alignChartHorizontally(yourFirstChart)
if(yourSecondChart.show) alignChartHorizontally(yourSeconcChart) 


// Synchronize all X Axes.
let isAxisXScaleChangeActive = false
const syncAxisXEventHandler = (axis, start, end) => {
   if (isAxisXScaleChangeActive) return
   isAxisXScaleChangeActive = true

   // Find all other X Axes.
   const otherAxes = allCharts
      .map(chart => chart.getDefaultAxisX())
      .filter(axis2 => axis2 !== axis)

   // Sync other X Axis intervals.  
   otherAxes.forEach((axis) => axis
      .setInterval(start, end, false, true)
   )

   isAxisXScaleChangeActive = false
}

//add both (or all) of your charts to this array:
allCharts = [myChart1, myChart2]

//adds event listener and handler to all your charts' scaleChange event emitters
allCharts.forEach(chart => chart.getDefaultAxisX().onScaleChange((start, end) => syncAxisXEventHandler(chart.getDefaultAxisX(), start, end)))
```

Adapted from: https://github.com/Arction/lcjs-showcase-trading/blob/master/src/app.ts